# Can't install AWSCLI on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

It's my second day trying to figure how to install AWSCLI on WSL. After realizing that WSL was sharing $PATH with Windows ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161976/aws-on-ubuntu-wsl ) I was sure that AWSCLI would install just fine! So I installed pip3 just to make sure and tried to install AWSCLI. No errors, everything look fine, but... hu hu, there's a problem, AWS is no where to be found...

[image: CLI]

Any idea how to fix that ?

Answer (score 3):

For a specific user

- Use this command `pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user` to install `awscli` package. When you use the `--user` switch, pip installs the AWS CLI to `~/.local/bin`.
- Add an export command at the end of your shell initialization file, `.bashrc` for bash, `.zshrc` for zsh etc. For example, `export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH`. This command inserts the path, `~/.local/bin` in this example, at the front of the existing `PATH` variable.
- Reload the profile into your current session to put those changes into effect `source ~/.bashrc`.
- Verify that the AWS CLI installed correctly.

```
$ which aws
/home/john/.local/bin/aws

$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.209 Python/3.7.3 Linux/4.19.59-microsoft-standard botocore/1.12.199
```

**Source:** [Install the AWS CLI on Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html)